# Interpolating uneven data with SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, interpolation

I've been going through examples on the [documentation for `scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) and I can't figure out how I would take data that's unevenly spaced and interpolate it, as all of the tutorials use linspaces -- which are evenly spaced.

For example, I have some data spread like so:

```
[--1--4-----5-3-22---55-]
```

where each `-` represents a missing value.

How would I go about fitting an interpolation function to this using `scipy.interpolate`?

Comment: Have you tried setting your `x` vector equal to the indices for which you have data, and your `y` vector equal to the values at those indices? I am not sure that this will work in your case, but it came to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) works fine with unevenly spaced data. For example,

```
import re
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = '--1--4-----5-3-22---55-'
parts = [c for c in re.split(r'(-|\d+)', text) if c]
data = np.array([(x, int(y)) for x, y in enumerate(parts) if y != '-'])
x, y = data.T
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

newx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max())
newy = f(newx)
plt.plot(newx, newy)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=20)
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: Thanks! As a followup, is it possible for me to extend the interpolating function past the data? 

When I try to do this simply by running it on the linspace(0,some_number>x.max()) I get a ValueError that there's a value in x_new above the interpolation range.

Comment: @zmjjmz its in the docs <http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d>: just add `bounds_error=False`